# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes' is not allowed to appear in element 'jaxb:bindings'

Tags: eclipse, maven, jaxb, xjc

I've checkoud one project... and trying solve some problems in Eclipse Luna 4.4.0. In one of the maven project I have following xjb file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jaxb:bindings
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    xmlns:xjc= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd
">
...
...
```

but Eclipse reporting me Problem >
    ***cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes' is not allowed to appear in element 'jaxb:bindings'***

does anybody know why?

Answer (score 3):

The [bindingschema_2_0.xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd) seems to be inadequate. It declares the `extensionBindingPrefixes` attribute, but does not to use it in the global `bindings` element.

The use of `jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes` attribute in the code you posted looks correct to me.

Me personaly, I have never used used `xsi:location` in binding files. You can safely remove it.

Comment: If I remove the `xsi:schemaLocation` i will get rid of the error, but also new warning will appear: `No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document`

Comment: @Curamrda Not every document has a DTD or an XML Schema and not every document needs one. I don't think the warning *generally* makes sense.

Comment: Hm... but the code is not mine. I dont wanna change it. i found the opening tag in many code examples, so i need to convince Eclipse to remove the error. Still looking for solution :(

Comment: I can at least help you on this stupid eclipse warning re. missing schema or DTD. Just add an XML doctype instruction followed with the name of the root element - this represents a minimalistic (i.e. empty) inline "doctype" definition. I typically add a comment to explain what this is supposed to mean. HTH!
<!DOCTYPE bindings> <!-- to silence buggy eclipse validation warnings -->